# Can't upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 unofficial package issues

Tags: upgrade, package-management

I have a similar issue to [Can't upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766185/cant-upgrade-from-15-10-to-16-04?rq=1)  My attempted upgrade with `sudo update-manager -d` always fails with an unofficial package error.

```
$ grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log 
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 > ( perl ) (< 5.22.1~)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ amd64 ] < 204-5ubuntu20.19 > ( admin )
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libopencv-core2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-core2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-core:amd64 Conflicts on xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl [ amd64 ] < 0.6.0-0ubuntu4 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-core:amd64 Conflicts on xserver-xorg-video-modesetting [ amd64 ] < 0.8.1-1build1 > ( x11 )
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Breaks on libgnome-control-center1 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
Broken libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 Conflicts on account-plugin-windows-live [ amd64 ] < 0.11+14.04.20140409.1-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken libxapian22v5:amd64 Conflicts on libxapian22 [ amd64 ] < 1.2.16-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libtag1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libtag1c2a [ amd64 ] < 1.9.1-2 > ( libs )
Broken libproxy1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libproxy1 [ amd64 ] < 0.4.11-0ubuntu4 > ( libs )
Broken libasprintf0v5:amd64 Breaks on libasprintf0c2 [ amd64 ] < 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libkrb5support0:amd64 Breaks on libkdb5-7 [ amd64 ] < 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 > ( libs ) (< 1.13~alpha1-1)
Broken libopencv-imgproc2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-imgproc2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken bluez:amd64 Conflicts on bluez-alsa [ amd64 ] < 4.101-0ubuntu13.1 > ( admin )
Broken libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsigc++-2.0-0c2a [ amd64 ] < 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libopenmpi1.10:amd64 Conflicts on libopenmpi1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 > ( libs )
Broken bluez-obexd:amd64 Conflicts on obexd-client [ amd64 ] < 0.46-1ubuntu7 > ( admin )
Broken libical1a:amd64 Breaks on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libwinpr-thread0.1:amd64 Breaks on libfreerdp1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1)
Broken python3-cupshelpers:amd64 Breaks on python-cupshelpers [ amd64 ] < 1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.6 > ( gnome ) (< 1.5.0+20140805-0ubuntu3)
Broken unity-lens-music:amd64 Conflicts on unity-scope-musicstores [ amd64 ] < 6.9.0+14.04.20151120.2-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken overlay-scrollbar:amd64 Conflicts on overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 [ amd64 ] < 0.2.16+r359+14.04.20131129-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libebml4v5:amd64 Breaks on libebml4 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.0-2+deb8u1build0.14.04.1 > ( libs )
Broken libsidplay1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsidplay1 [ amd64 ] < 1.36.59-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libglibmm-2.4-1c2a [ amd64 ] < 2.39.93-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libmatroska6v5:amd64 Breaks on libmatroska6 [ amd64 ] < 1.4.1-2+deb8u1build0.14.04.1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-filesystem1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-filesystem1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-python1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-python1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libid3-3.8.3v5:amd64 Conflicts on libid3-3.8.3c2a [ amd64 ] < 3.8.3-15 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-regex1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libopencv-calib3d2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-calib3d2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl20:amd64 Breaks on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-date-time1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-date-time1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-mpi1.54.0:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-highgui2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-test1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-test1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-wave1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-wave1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libsidplay2v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsidplay2 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.1-14 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-iostreams1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-program-options1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-program-options1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libgsl2:amd64 Conflicts on libgsl0ldbl [ amd64 ] < 1.16+dfsg-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libopencv-flann2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-flann2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-coroutine1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-coroutine1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libopencv-legacy2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-legacy2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libfarstream-0.2-5:amd64 Conflicts on libfarstream-0.2-2 [ amd64 ] < 0.2.3-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libcolumbus1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libcolumbus1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0+14.04.20140325.3-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-serialization1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-serialization1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-thread1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-thread1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-timer1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-timer1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-log1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-log1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-chrono1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-chrono1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-math1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-math1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libopencv-features2d2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-features2d2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-signals1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-signals1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-context1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-context1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-random1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-random1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libgnutls28:amd64 Depends on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.7)
Broken libgnutls28:amd64 Depends on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.7)
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-system1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-system1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-mpi1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libgtkmm-3.0-1 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.1-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-atomic1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-atomic1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-exception1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-exception1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost1.58-tools-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.54-tools-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost1.58-tools-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.54-tools-dev [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libboost-graph1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-graph1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-locale1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-locale1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libopencv-video2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-video2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libboost1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libopencv-objdetect2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-objdetect2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libopencv-contrib2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-contrib2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libtag1v5-vanilla:amd64 Breaks on libtag1-vanilla [ amd64 ] < 1.9.1-2 > ( libs )
Broken mysql-server-5.7:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-client-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( database )
Broken mysql-server-5.7:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-server-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( database )
Broken mysql-server-5.7:amd64 Conflicts on virtual-mysql-server [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken mysql-client-core-5.7:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-client-core-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( database )
Broken fonts-guru-extra:amd64 Breaks on ttf-punjabi-fonts [ amd64 ] < 1:0.5.14ubuntu1 > ( fonts ) (< 2:1.0)
Broken libopenobex2:amd64 Breaks on libopenobex1 [ amd64 ] < 1.5-2.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.7.1-4)
Broken libsnappy1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsnappy1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04 -> 2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3)
Broken libpcrecpp0v5:amd64 Conflicts on libpcrecpp0 [ amd64 ] < 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3 > ( libs )
Broken libmircommon-dev:amd64 Breaks on mircommon-dev [ amd64 ] < 0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1 > ( libdevel ) (< 0.6)
Broken libtotem-plparser-common:amd64 Breaks on libtotem-plparser17 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.5-1 > ( libs )
Broken libpyzy-1.0-0v5:amd64 Conflicts on libpyzy-1.0-0 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.1-4 > ( libs )
Broken vlc:amd64 Breaks on vlc-plugin-pulse [ amd64 ] < 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 > ( video ) (< 2.2.1-4~)
Broken libvncclient1:amd64 Breaks on libvncserver0 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.9+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 > ( libs ) (< 0.9.9+dfsg-3)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-chardet-whl [ amd64 ] < 2.2.1-2~ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 2.3.0-2)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-colorama-whl [ amd64 ] < 0.2.5-0.1ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 0.3.6-1)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-distlib-whl [ amd64 ] < 0.1.8-1ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 0.2.2-1)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-html5lib-whl [ amd64 ] < 0.999-3~ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 0.999-4)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-requests-whl [ amd64 ] < 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3 > ( python ) (< 2.9.1-3)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-setuptools-whl [ amd64 ] < 3.3-1ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 20.1.1-1)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-six-whl [ amd64 ] < 1.5.2-1ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 1.10.0-3)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-urllib3-whl [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-1ubuntu4 > ( python ) (< 1.13.1-2)
Broken mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-server-core-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( database )
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.58.0:amd64 Conflicts on libboost-mpi-python1.54.0 [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( python )
Broken libopencv-ml2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-ml2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl-pango15:amd64 Depends on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.15.8)
Broken libpangomm-1.4-1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libpangomm-1.4-1 [ amd64 ] < 2.34.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libatkmm-1.6-1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libatkmm-1.6-1 [ amd64 ] < 2.22.7-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libcheese7:amd64 Depends on cheese-common [ amd64 ] < 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.18.1-2ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu2)
Broken libvlccore7:amd64 Depends on vlc-data [ amd64 ] < 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 -> 2.2.2-5 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2)
Broken nautilus-sendto-empathy:amd64 Depends on empathy [ amd64 ] < 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2 -> 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( universe/gnome ) (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2)
Broken qtsensors5-dev:amd64 Depends on libqt5sensors5-dev [ amd64 ] < 5.2.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2 -> 5.5.1-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libdevel ) (= 5.2.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2)
Broken libclucene-contribs1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libclucene-contribs1 [ amd64 ] < 2.3.3.4-4build1 > ( libs )
Broken libmetacity-private0a:amd64 Depends on metacity-common [ amd64 ] < 1:2.34.13-0ubuntu4.1 -> 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu0.1 > ( misc ) (= 1:2.34.13-0ubuntu4.1)
Broken libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 Breaks on libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a [ amd64 ] < 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libperl5.18:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1)
Broken libclucene-core1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libclucene-core1 [ amd64 ] < 2.3.3.4-4build1 > ( libs )
Broken libcheese-gtk23:amd64 Depends on libcheese7 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken libcairomm-1.0-1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libcairomm-1.0-1 [ amd64 ] < 1.10.0-1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.54.0 [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libs )
Broken libidl-2-0:amd64 Breaks on libidl0 [ amd64 ] < 0.8.14-0.2ubuntu4 > ( libs ) (< 0.8.14-3)
Broken totem-mozilla:amd64 Depends on totem [ amd64 ] < 3.10.1-1ubuntu4 -> 3.18.1-1ubuntu4 > ( gnome ) (= 3.10.1-1ubuntu4)
Broken libecal-1.2-15:amd64 Depends on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.0)
Broken libqt53d5:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-2-1 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken checkbox-ng-service:amd64 Depends on checkbox-ng [ amd64 ] < 0.3-2 -> 0.23-2 > ( utils ) (= 0.3-2)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken librhythmbox-core7:amd64 Depends on libtotem-plparser17 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.5-1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64 Depends on libsidplay1 [ amd64 ] < 1.36.59-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libgcr-3-1:amd64 Depends on libgcr-base-3-1 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.1-1 -> 3.18.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 3.10.1-1)
Broken openmpi-checkpoint:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 > ( libs ) (= 1.6.5-8)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken libical1a:amd64 Breaks on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libsidplay1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsidplay1 [ amd64 ] < 1.36.59-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libleveldb1:amd64 Depends on libsnappy1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl20:amd64 Breaks on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs )
Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04 > ( java )
Broken libgnutls28:amd64 Depends on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.7)
Broken libgnutls28:amd64 Depends on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.7)
Broken libsnappy1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsnappy1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04 -> 2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3)
Broken libtotem-plparser-common:amd64 Breaks on libtotem-plparser17 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.5-1 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl-pango15:amd64 Depends on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.15.8)
Broken libecal-1.2-15:amd64 Depends on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.0)
Broken librhythmbox-core7:amd64 Depends on libtotem-plparser17 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.5-1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64 Depends on libsidplay1 [ amd64 ] < 1.36.59-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken libical1a:amd64 Breaks on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libsidplay1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsidplay1 [ amd64 ] < 1.36.59-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libleveldb1:amd64 Depends on libsnappy1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl20:amd64 Breaks on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs )
Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04 > ( java )
Broken libgnutls28:amd64 Depends on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (>= 2.7)
Broken libsnappy1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsnappy1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04 -> 2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3)
Broken libtotem-plparser-common:amd64 Breaks on libtotem-plparser17 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.5-1 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl-pango15:amd64 Depends on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.15.8)
Broken python3.4-minimal:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3)
Broken libpython3.4:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3)
Broken libecal-1.2-15:amd64 Depends on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.0)
Broken libecal-1.2-16:amd64 Depends on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.0)
Broken librhythmbox-core7:amd64 Depends on libtotem-plparser17 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.5-1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.2.0)
Broken libedata-cal-1.2-20:amd64 Depends on libecal-1.2-15 [ amd64 ] < 3.8.5-1ubuntu3 > ( libs ) (>= 3.7.90)
Broken libedata-cal-1.2-23:amd64 Depends on libecal-1.2-16 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.4-0ubuntu1.5 > ( libs ) (>= 3.10.0)
Broken gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64 Depends on libsidplay1 [ amd64 ] < 1.36.59-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56:amd64 Depends on libsnappy1v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.3-2 > ( libs )
Broken libavformat-ffmpeg56:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.7)
Broken libavformat-ffmpeg56:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.7)
Broken gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 Depends on libavformat-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken python-tables-lib:amd64 Depends on libsnappy1v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.3-2 > ( libs )
Broken libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 Depends on libavformat-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libchromaprint0:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libchromaprint0:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 Depends on libavformat-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken vlc-nox:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken vlc-nox:amd64 Depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken vlc-nox:amd64 Depends on libavformat-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libopencv-legacy2.4v5:amd64 Depends on libopencv-highgui2.4v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1)
Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016f-0ubuntu0.14.04 > ( java )
Broken ffmpeg:amd64 Depends on libavfilter-ffmpeg5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libopencv-objdetect2.4v5:amd64 Depends on libopencv-highgui2.4v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1)
Broken libopencv-contrib2.4v5:amd64 Depends on libopencv-highgui2.4v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1)
Broken python3.4:amd64 Depends on python3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3)
Broken libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 Depends on libavfilter-ffmpeg5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken libav-tools:amd64 Depends on ffmpeg [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/video )
Broken vlc:amd64 Depends on vlc-nox [ amd64 ] < 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 -> 2.2.2-5 > ( universe/net ) (= 2.2.2-5)
Broken mplayer:amd64 Depends on libavformat-ffmpeg56 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken pianobar:amd64 Depends on libavfilter-ffmpeg5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs ) (>= 7:2.4)
Broken openjdk-7-jre:amd64 Depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3 > ( java ) (= 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
Broken icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64 Depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3 > ( java ) (= 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
Broken python-tables:amd64 Depends on python-tables-lib [ amd64 ] < 3.1.1-0ubuntu1 -> 3.2.2-2 > ( universe/python ) (>= 3.2.2-2)
Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 Depends on libopencv-contrib2.4v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libleveldb1:amd64 Depends on libsnappy1 [ amd64 ] < 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken mplayer2:amd64 Depends on mplayer [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/video ) (>= 2:1.2)
Broken openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 Depends on openjdk-7-jre [ amd64 ] < 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3 > ( java ) (= 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
Broken handbrake-gtk:amd64 Depends on gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1 -> 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken eth:amd64 Depends on libleveldb1 [ amd64 ] < 1.15.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken libethereum:amd64 Depends on libleveldb1 [ amd64 ] < 1.15.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken libdvdnav4:amd64 Breaks on mplayer2 [ amd64 ] < 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/oldlibs ) (< 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4)
Broken mplayer2:amd64 Depends on mplayer [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/video ) (>= 2:1.2)
Broken libdvdnav4:amd64 Breaks on mplayer2 [ amd64 ] < 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/oldlibs ) (< 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4)
Broken mplayer2:amd64 Depends on mplayer [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/video ) (>= 2:1.2)
Broken libdvdnav4:amd64 Breaks on mplayer2 [ amd64 ] < 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/oldlibs ) (< 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4)
Broken mplayer2:amd64 Depends on mplayer [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/video ) (>= 2:1.2)
Broken libdvdnav4:amd64 Breaks on mplayer2 [ amd64 ] < 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/oldlibs ) (< 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4)
Broken mplayer2:amd64 Depends on mplayer [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/video ) (>= 2:1.2)
Broken libdvdnav4:amd64 Breaks on mplayer2 [ amd64 ] < 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/oldlibs ) (< 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4)
Broken mplayer2:amd64 Depends on mplayer [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/video ) (>= 2:1.2)
```

I have a total of 151 packages failing I believe.  Do I need to remove all of them?

```
$grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log |cut -d":" -f1|cut -d" " -f2 | sort | uniq > /tmp/failed-package-updates.txt
aptitude
bluez
bluez-obexd
checkbox-ng-service
eth
ffmpeg
findutils
fonts-guru-extra
gnome-control-center
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
gstreamer1.0-libav
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
handbrake-gtk
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm
libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
libasprintf0v5
libatkmm-1.6-1v5
libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
libavdevice-ffmpeg56
libavfilter-ffmpeg5
libavformat-ffmpeg56
libav-tools
libboost1.58-dev
libboost1.58-tools-dev
libboost-atomic1.58-dev
libboost-chrono1.58-dev
libboost-context1.58-dev
libboost-coroutine1.58-dev
libboost-date-time1.58-dev
libboost-exception1.58-dev
libboost-filesystem1.58-dev
libboost-graph1.58-dev
libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0
libboost-graph-parallel1.58-dev
libboost-iostreams1.58-dev
libboost-locale1.58-dev
libboost-log1.58-dev
libboost-math1.58-dev
libboost-mpi1.54.0
libboost-mpi1.58-dev
libboost-mpi-python1.58.0
libboost-mpi-python1.58-dev
libboost-program-options1.58-dev
libboost-python1.58-dev
libboost-random1.58-dev
libboost-regex1.58-dev
libboost-serialization1.58-dev
libboost-signals1.58-dev
libboost-system1.58-dev
libboost-test1.58-dev
libboost-thread1.58-dev
libboost-timer1.58-dev
libboost-wave1.58-dev
libcairomm-1.0-1v5
libcheese7
libcheese-gtk23
libchromaprint0
libclucene-contribs1v5
libclucene-core1v5
libcogl20
libcogl-pango15
libcolumbus1v5
libcwidget3
libcwidget3v5
libdvdnav4
libebml4v5
libecal-1.2-15
libecal-1.2-16
libedata-cal-1.2-20
libedata-cal-1.2-23
libethereum
libfarstream-0.2-5
libgcr-3-1
libglibmm-2.4-1v5
libgnutls28
libgnutls30
libgsl2
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
libgtkmm-3.0-1v5
libical1a
libid3-3.8.3v5
libidl-2-0
libkrb5support0
libleveldb1
libmatroska6v5
libmetacity-private0a
libmircommon-dev
libopencv-calib3d2.4v5
libopencv-contrib2.4v5
libopencv-core2.4v5
libopencv-features2d2.4v5
libopencv-flann2.4v5
libopencv-highgui2.4v5
libopencv-imgproc2.4v5
libopencv-legacy2.4v5
libopencv-ml2.4v5
libopencv-objdetect2.4v5
libopencv-video2.4v5
libopenmpi1.10
libopenobex2
libpangomm-1.4-1v5
libpcrecpp0v5
libperl5.18
libproxy1v5
libpython3.4
libpython3.4-stdlib
libpyzy-1.0-0v5
libqt53d5
librhythmbox-core7
libsidplay1v5
libsidplay2v5
libsigc++-2.0-0v5
libsnappy1v5
libtag1v5
libtag1v5-vanilla
libtotem-plparser-common
libvlccore7
libvncclient1
libwinpr-thread0.1
libxapian22v5
mplayer
mplayer2
mysql-client-core-5.7
mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-core-5.7
nautilus-sendto-empathy
openjdk-7-jdk
openjdk-7-jre
openjdk-7-jre-headless
openmpi-checkpoint
overlay-scrollbar
perl-base
pianobar
python3.4
python3.4-minimal
python3-cupshelpers
python-pip-whl
python-tables
python-tables-lib
qtsensors5-dev
systemd
totem-mozilla
tzdata-java
unity-control-center-faces
unity-lens-music
vlc
vlc-nox
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-mouse
xserver-xorg-video-s3
xserver-xorg-video-sis
```

Comment: It might be a silly question, but have you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: Yes it says Hit for most of them and Ign for a few, I can post full output if necessary

Comment: It might be worth editing it into the question. It seems like a broken packages question, of which there are many. On way to attempt to fix them up may be `sudo apt-get install -f`. It ought to be a safe command to run, I'm no expert in these types of questions though.

Comment: First remove all the ppa using `ppa-purge`. All of them. then do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. then do the `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up completely removing a few packages I knew were non essential in `synaptic` like pianobar, eth, handbrake, mplayer, mplayer2 and vlc and then reran

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

and the unofficial package error went away and I was able to successfully upgrade.  It did still give a warning that 151 packages will not be upgraded, but I just had to hit okay.  16.04 and my programs seem to be working smoothly so far!